# Black line over picture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

If I point mouse over the picture Json   I get a **black line** over the picture
[What does it look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPG4L.png)
How i can delete this line

```
<div class="col-sm-4" ><p align="center"><%=link_to image_tag("Json.png", size: "32") , "/posts.json" %></p></div>
```

https://myapp-v3.herokuapp.com/  -- Json  picture in the middle of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
myapp-v3.herokuapp.com/media="all"
a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}
myapp-v3.herokuapp.com/media="all"
a:visited {
    color: #666;
}
```

Delete or fix the top one...